# Clicking gains +1% of your CpS

Tags: cookie-clicker

I have this upgrade in Cookie Clicker, but I have no idea what "Clicking gains +1% of your CpS" means.  Can anyone provide any info?  Once I buy it, clicking doesn't seem to make any difference.

What impact does "+1% of your CpS" give?

Comment: Unfamiliar with this game, but Ive seen the same thing in a Katamari clicker. CpS generally means clicks per second. If you consider that this is only a small percentage, it can be easy to miss the increase. I personally had to confirm the similar mechanic using maths, as at medium-high levels, it was still not completely obvious. Hopefully someone with experience can elaborate.

Comment: Hmm, I thought CpS meant Cookies per Second.

Comment: For cookie clicker, it does mean "Cookies per Second".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clicking doesn't increase your CpS if that's what you're thinking; it means that if every time you manually clicked it would give you 20 cookies, and your CPS was 100, clicking now gives you 21 cookies. This scales up as your CpS increases. So if you buy another building and get 200CpS, your clicks now generate 22 cookies each.

Comment: In other words, your "clicking power" is increased by a fraction of your passive CpS income. This upgrade gets very important later on, when you  buy Golden Cookie upgrades and become able to gain "x7 CpS" and "x777 clicking power" simultaneously. See [wiki](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Cookie) for more combinations and analysis.

Answer (score -3):

Each time you click, 1% of your CPS is added to your current number of cookies.
Say you get the upgrade giving you this. You are gaining 4500 cookies per click with a CPS of 1 million. 
1000000/100=10000 therefore you now gain 14500 cookies per click.

Comment: This answer adds nothing not covered by the old, accepted answer. Duplicate answers are not useful and may be subject to deletion.